# Having problems solving python Practice Quiz: While Loops

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I got an exercise like this:

Fill in the blanks to complete the while loop so that it returns the sum of all the divisors of a number, without including the number itself. As a reminder, a divisor is a number that divides into another without a remainder. To do this, you will need to:

Initialize the "divisor" and "total" variables with starting values

Complete the while loop condition

Increment the "divisor" variable inside the while loop

Complete the return statement

```
# Fill in the blanks so that the while loop continues to run while the
# "divisor" variable is less than the "number" parameter.

def sum_divisors(number):
# Initialize the appropriate variables
  ___ = ___
  ___ = ___

  # Avoid dividing by 0 and negative numbers 
  # in the while loop by exiting the function
  # if "number" is less than one
  if number < 1:
    return 0 

  # Complete the while loop
  while ___:
    if number % divisor == 0:
      total += divisor
    # Increment the correct variable
    ___ += 1

  # Return the correct variable 
  return ___


print(sum_divisors(0)) # Should print 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should print 1
# 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should print 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should print 1+2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```

Here's my answer but clearly there are problems.... I have just started to learn python so it's quite confusing.......

```
# Fill in the blanks so that the while loop continues to run while the
# "divisor" variable is less than the "number" parameter.

def sum_divisors(number):
# Initialize the appropriate variables
  divisor = 1
  total = 1

  # Avoid dividing by 0 and negative numbers 
  # in the while loop by exiting the function
  # if "number" is less than one
  if number < 1:
    return 0 

  # Complete the while loop
  while number // divisor == 0:
    if number % divisor == 0:
      total += divisor
    # Increment the correct variable
    divisor += 1

  # Return the correct variable 
  return total


print(sum_divisors(0)) # Should print 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should print 1
# 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should print 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should print 1+2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```

result:
0
1
1
1

Comment: You are close, but you have two mistakes. Rather than give you the answer, I'll ask questions to make you think about the problems. Why should `total` start at 1? Why is your while loops condition what it is? Walk through the program with numbers mentally and think about what happens as you count up to 4.

Comment: OH! `total` should start at 0! And the while loops condition was wrong too, just like @rishi-sanjeev answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since your first two tests pass, I'll focus on the third one, 36. On this line, `while number // divisor == 0:`, it says while number, 36 for our purposes, divided by (without any decimals) divisor, which is 1, is 0. 36 divided by one will never be 0, so the while loops will never start. You may want `while divisor <= number/2:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Fill in the blanks so that the while loop continues to run while the
# "divisor" variable is less than the "number" parameter.

def sum_divisors(number):
# Initialize the appropriate variables
  divisor = 1
  total = 0

  # Avoid dividing by 0 and negative numbers 
  # in the while loop by exiting the function
  # if "number" is less than one
  if number < 1:
    return 0 

  # Complete the while loop
  while divisor <= number/2:
    if number % divisor == 0:
      total += divisor
    # Increment the correct variable
    divisor += 1

  # Return the correct variable 
  return total


print(sum_divisors(0)) # Should print 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should print 1
# 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should print 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should print 1+2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all numbers can be divided by 1, I'd go with `divisor = 1`. Also, total has to be 0.

Then, you just need to compare the number and the divisor values for the code to work:

```
def sum_divisors(number):
  divisor = 1
  total = 0

  if number < 1:
    return 0 

  while number > divisor:
    if number % divisor == 0:
      total += divisor
      print("divisor = " + str(divisor)) # Make sure that the checks confirm the expected results.
    divisor += 1

  return total
```